# Cursor going backwards (again)

Tags: cursor

My cursor is going backwards. Last time I was advised to install:
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2415167&p=13846463#post13846463

I think it worked for some time but no more now, I am still getting that problem. I tried to install it again, and got following message:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweaks is already the newest version (3.28.1-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libapache2-mod-php8.0
Use 'sudo apt auto remove to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
```

I did not remove it. Please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: What do you mean by "going backwards". Gnome tweaks is for customizations, it isn't likely to fix any problems unless the "problem" is that you don't like the designed behavior of the system and want to customize it. Also you have 109 packages that are pending update. Update your system before you try to install anything new. Gnome tweaks is already installed on your system.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.